# WPF C# : Label not big enough

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, wpf-controls, label

I am using WPF for my C# application on which i have several labels in which the texts don't fit. What I want is to make my text move inside the label so that the user can see the entire text. 
Example : let's say that my text is 20 characters long, by my label has enough space for only 15 characters. What I want is that my label to display the first 15 characters (characters 1-15) then after 1 second the same characters without the first but with another at the end (so characters 2-16) then the next (characters 3-17) and so on until the last 15 characters (characters 5-20) and then I want them to start from the beginning (the characters 1-15 again).

How can I do that ? One way is (obviously) to use a Timer, but I am sure that a more elegant solution exists.

Comment: Have you considered using a tooltip?

Comment: I had to do something like this yesterday.  I opted to keep the WHOLE string and adjust the font size.

Comment: @Shoe, ToolTip is not want I want for this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GarryVass, my example can be easy resolved by changing the font size, I agree, but in my problem the string can be very long, much longer than the label. That's why I want to use this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is code for a quick-and-dirty scrolling control that should do what you want as soon as the user mouses over the control.

```
        <Canvas Name="brd" 
                ClipToBounds="True"
                Margin="10" 
                Height="20" Width="150" 
                Background="White"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <StackPanel Name="spl1" 
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Canvas.Left="0">
                <TextBlock Name="tbk1"
                           Margin="10,0"
                           MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=brd,Path=ActualWidth}"
                           Text="A display of test text that is wider than the control."/>
                <TextBlock MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=brd,Path=ActualWidth}"
                           Margin="10,0"
                           Text="{Binding ElementName=tbk1,Path=Text}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Canvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="scroll">
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="-200" Duration="0:0:4"  
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="spl1"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger> 
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="scroll"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Canvas.Triggers>
        </Canvas>
```

There is one part that you will need to change for proper operation, that I did not implement.  The `<DoubleAnimation To="-200"...` will need to be changed.  Ideally the value for `To` will be the negative of the `ActualWidth` property of the `tbk1` control.  This will require both an element binding to get the value and a `ValueConverter` to make that value negative.

If you don't want to go to the trouble of a converter, you can just make the `To` value sufficiently large to accommodate the longest text that you expect.  That will get you reasonably close.

You can, of course, tweak this more to provide a smoother transition at the end of one animation cycle and the start of the next.

**EDIT**

OK, I couldn't leave it half finished.  Below is the updated XAML for smooth operation, and the included code for the `ValueConverter`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Converters:ChangeSignConverter x:Key="ChangeSignConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

        <Canvas Name="brd" 
                ClipToBounds="True"
                Margin="10" 
                Height="20" Width="150" 
                Background="White"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <StackPanel Name="spl1" 
                        Margin="5,0,0,0"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Canvas.Left="0">
                <TextBlock Name="tbk1"
                           Padding="0,0,10,0"
                           MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=brd,Path=ActualWidth}"
                           Text="A display of test text that is wider than the control."/>
                <TextBlock MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=brd,Path=ActualWidth}"
                           Text="{Binding ElementName=tbk1,Path=Text}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Canvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="scroll">
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="{Binding ElementName=tbk1,Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource ChangeSignConverter}}" 
                                             Duration="0:0:4"  
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="spl1"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger> 
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="scroll"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Canvas.Triggers>
        </Canvas>
```

Converter class:

```
class ChangeSignConverter : IValueConverter
{
  object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return Convert.ToDouble(value) * -1;
  }

  object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return Convert.ToDouble(value) * -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: very nice solution, works very well, but I didn't managed to make it work without going with my mouse on the textblock. Here I believe I should offer more details: so my program reads files and the label that I am talking about (the one that needs the scrolls) displays the name of the file. Because the name of the file can be very long, I want this "scroll" effect. So, how can I make my text scroll all the time,without going with my mouse on it ?

Comment: @TheQuestioner, if you don't want to require the user to move their mouse, you can set a different EventTrigger that matches your requirements better.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx

Comment: <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded"> , that was all that I had to change. Thanks a lot dude ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the WPF [animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx#animationtypes) functionality. You create a custom control which has a TextBlock inside. Define the control's width (which would be smaller than the textblock's width. Then define the storyboard and double animation to animate it however you want it (slower / faster, only animate to the right, animate right then left and so on).

This is just an idea. I'm currently in a rush, but I can provide you with additional code, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I would also use Timer for functionality you described. I think there are not many other solutions, if you insist on changing Label in some specified time interval. On the other hand, I would probably use ToolTip, which I think is more intuitive for this.

Comment: Thanks, ToolTip is not want I want for this.